# AudioManager - Is there a way to get the relevant Audio Stream?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

When calling AudioManager's method `adjustSuggestedStreamVolume`, the system adjusts the "relevant" audio stream. Is there a callback or anything that can help me find out which stream was adjusted?

For instance, if the user is playing a video in my app and presses the volume buttons, the above method will adjust the MUSIC Audio Stream. Is there a way to access this programmatically?